# set the value for aspx label element from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling a Web API using javascript,
I have an aspx label element with id "blbtest".

```
    <asp:Label ID="blbtest" Text="" runat="server ClientIDMode="Static">
```

I want to store the value of the name variable in this label but I get an error

This is the js code:

```
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
       request.open('GET', "https://hplussport.com/api/products?qty=2");

       request.onload = function () {
       var response = request.response;
       var parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
       console.log(parsedData);
       var name = parsedData[0].name;
       var products = document.createElement('li');
    //products.innerHTML = name;
    //document.body.appendChild(products);
   var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=blbtest.ClientID%>');

  lbl.innerText = name;
  };
  request.send();
```

The error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (script.js:14:19)

The commented lines are working.
But I want to display the name of the product in the label element when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried this and it worked :)

```
    document.getElementById('blbtest').innerHTML = name;
```